# Extending the size limitation of System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**tl;dr;** How to overcome the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` size limitation of 1500 members when modifying an AD group?

In the past I made a powershell script that basically scans (now more than) 50 AD locations for members, and add them all to a common group. Full documentation and source available here: http://fsteff.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/adldap-user-directories-setup-in.html

I use the following object to hold all the members of the group:

```
$oGroup = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry -ArgumentList "$LDAP/$GroupDN", $sUser, $sPass
```

and use the following two commands to first add new members, and then remove expired members:

```
$oGroup.Invoke("add", "$LDAP/$userDN")
$oGroup.Invoke("remove","$LDAP/$Member")
```

When the search is complete, I commit the change to AD using:

```
$oGroup.CommitChanges()
$oGroup.RefreshCache()
$oGroup.Close()
```

This is all working fine, with the exception that I've now found out that `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` has a **size limitation which truncates the size to 1500 members**.

I've been searching online, and have found several options to overcome the size limitation when reading the group, using various ways of chunking the date. However now of those can be used in this situation, as I need to create and commit to AD a group with more than 1500 members.

Advice or pointers for a solution is highly appreciated.



Note1: Yes I could swap  the order of 'add' and 'remove', to perhaps save some entries, but I'm missing hundredths of members, so it wouldn't suffice.)

Comment: Can you not perform the operation multiple times in batches of `< 1500`?

Comment: Unfortunately I see no handles to split up the writing of a group into AD. (Reading is a different matter)

Comment: Just call `CommitChanges` after you've added 1500 members, then add 1500 more and call `CommitChanges` again... repeat.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Did you try that and it worked? I recall reading that after adding 1500 members, additional add's will simply be ignored.  Will investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: I haven't tried it, no. But it must be possible. Maybe I'll try it out when I get back to work tomorrow.